# Finding points of (dis)continuities of a function $f:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R$ defined piece-wisely

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let a function $f:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R$ be defined by $$f(x,y,z)=\begin{cases}|x+y|,&\text{if }(x,y,z)\in\Bbb Q^3\\-|y+z|,&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

I would like to find all the points of (dis)continuities.

I first tried investigating all the points $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3$ for which it holds $|x+y|=-|y+z|,$ which is possible iff $\begin{cases}x+y=0\\y+z=0\end{cases}\implies(x,y,z)=x_0(1,-1,1), x_0\in\Bbb R$

and therefore $\lim\limits_{(x,y,z)\to(x_0,-x_0,x_0)}f(x,y,z)=0$

Now, for $c\in S=\Bbb R^3\setminus\operatorname{span}(1,-1,1),$ I thought I could make use of the density of $\Bbb Q^3$ in $\Bbb R^3$ and $\Bbb R^3\setminus\Bbb Q^3$ and argue that, if $c\in\Bbb Q^3,$ for each $r>0$ the open ball $B(c,r)$ contains a sequence $(c_n)_n$ in $\Bbb R^3\setminus\Bbb Q^3$ that converges to $c\in\Bbb Q^3$ and vice-versa, and hence, $f$ is discontinuous at $c$, but I'm not sure in my reasoning.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $r_n,s_n,t_n$ be rational numbers converging to $x,y,z$ respectively. Then  $f(r_n,s_n,t_n)=|r_n+s_n| \to |x+y|$.  Now let $r'_n,s'_n,t'_n$ be irrational numbers converging to $x,y,z$ respectively. Then  $f(r'_n,s'_n,t'_n)=-|s'_n+t'_n| \to -|y+z|$. This proves that $f$ is not continuous at $(x,y,z)$ whenever $|x+y| \neq -|y+z|$ which is true whenever $(x,y,z)$ does not belong to the span of $(1-1,1)$.